# Error when clicking an image button in Microsoft Edge

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

when I use the recently updated Microsoft Edge, it has the following problem.  It does not have it when I use other browsers like IE, Chrome, etc or previous versions of Microsoft Edge.

When I click an image button, it shows the error message of "Input string was not in a correct format"
and the Stack Trace is below:

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +7488663
   System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +115
   System.Double.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +192
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +189
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +14
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +690
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1743
```

Please help and advise what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that in your click event, you try to set some value from the page to a `Double` variable, but the original string is not a valid number format. The differences in browsers might be caused by the browsers use different locale settings (different locales might use `.` or `,` as decimal separator, or also thousands separators might come into play if number is large enough).

To give more help, we would need more details from your code related to the button (edit your question to provide more info).

Comment: We have checked the locale settings in the Server and PCs and found no problem.  Does Edge have its own locale settings?  Would you advise where it is?

Comment: More information that the program has been running for many years and it was fine with previous versions of Edge.

Comment: The programs were developed with Visual Studio, ASP and VB,   We are trying to provide related code for you to study, thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it is related to different locale settings, it was only the first thing I could think of based on why the parsing from string to double would fail. To find out more, I think you would have to debug and see what you actually get in as values on the server side before the parsing is done.